# Extract data from complicated file

Tags: python

I have several data files formatting like this:

```
Vectors                                                           #line 1
1.0000000000                                                      #line 2
    12.6482149405358335   -0.0349648302867427   -0.0028442567806109  #line 3
    -6.3543320038358670   10.3969225056801626    0.0194632704565655  #line 4
    -0.0024866905306129    0.0181600055076972   10.8458884055842208  #line 5
Points   11                                                       #line 6
  0.4305655209782699  0.8426201879889135  0.9003812234191031      #line 7
  0.6803904862706389  0.8422628581334592  0.8996231506556995      #line 8
  0.9310883880788197  0.8426914063929090  0.8988948816913620      #line 9
  0.1484226061614464  0.0918229591830411  0.5985391478206523      #line 10
  0.0871426252853240  0.4056041945139057  0.1025537266432366      #line 11
  0.6516284151939402  0.0944378154637135  0.6031197588423964      #line 12
  0.8977067858298895  0.0915250471034454  0.5994045156799004      #line 13
  0.1742665415904057  0.3420150165219624  0.6031464526385122      #line 14
  0.4219486318660017  0.3397275847827785  0.5972818153032335      #line 15
  0.6818585097829839  0.3402603219764870  0.5960939583330003      #line 16
  0.6605938016347537  0.8211262131757806  0.2511635759660038      #line 17
```

The 3rd to 5th line contain coordinates of vectors. And line 7th to end contained coordinates of points. I need to import coordinates x, y, z of each vector and point from data file to 2 corresponding matrices/lists: vectors and points for next calculation. Could you please suggest me a solution? It is quite complicated! Thank you so much!

python

```
import subprocess
import os
import sys
import math
import re
if __name__ == "__main__":
    with open('data.txt') as f:
        p = 11 #int(subprocess.call("grep Points"))
        dataline = f.readlines()
        re_vectors= re.compile("Vectors")
        re_points = re.compile("Points")
        vector_x = [], vector_y = [], vector_z = []
        point_x, point_y, point_z = [], [], []
        for line in dataline:
            if re_vectors.search(line):
                for i in range(0, 3):
                    parts = dataline[i+2].split()
                    vector_x = float(parts[0])
                    vector_y = float(parts[1])
                    vector_z = float(parts[2])
            print (vector_x, vector_y, vector_z)
            if re_points.search(line):
                for j in range(0, p):
                    parts = dataline[j+7].split()
                    point_x = float(parts[0])
                    point_y = float(parts[1])
                    point_z = float(parts[2])
            print (point_x, point_y, point_z)
```

Comment: Some questions. What is line 2? Does the number of vector stay constant (3)?

Comment: The file format is extremely simple, your code is unneccesarily complicated. For example why are you using `re` and regexes? Just do `if "Vectors" in line`... 
Why are you using `f.readlines()`? Just iterate over `f`. etc

Comment: Thank for asking! Line 2 just contain a parameters. number of vector is always 3.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two lists one for vectors and one for points. Is that what you want?

```
with open('data.txt', 'r') as f:
    s = f.readlines()

vectors = []
points = []
for row in s[1:5]:
    try:
        vector = row.split()
        vectors.append({'x': vector[0], 'y': vector[1], 'z': vector[2]})
    except:
        vector = row.split()
        vectors.append(vector)
for row in s[6:]:
    try:
        point = row.split()
        points.append({'x':point[0], 'y':point[1], 'z':point[2]})
    except:
        point = row.split()
        points.append(point)
print(vectors)
print(points)
```

Result

```
Vectors
['1.0000000000']
{'x': '12.6482149405358335', 'y': '-0.0349648302867427', 'z': '-0.0028442567806109'}
{'x': '-6.3543320038358670', 'y': '10.3969225056801626', 'z': '0.0194632704565655'}
{'x': '-0.0024866905306129', 'y': '0.0181600055076972', 'z': '10.8458884055842208'}
Points
{'x': '0.4305655209782699', 'y': '0.8426201879889135', 'z': '0.9003812234191031'}
{'x': '0.6803904862706389', 'y': '0.8422628581334592', 'z': '0.8996231506556995'}
{'x': '0.9310883880788197', 'y': '0.8426914063929090', 'z': '0.8988948816913620'}
{'x': '0.1484226061614464', 'y': '0.0918229591830411', 'z': '0.5985391478206523'}
{'x': '0.0871426252853240', 'y': '0.4056041945139057', 'z': '0.1025537266432366'}
{'x': '0.6516284151939402', 'y': '0.0944378154637135', 'z': '0.6031197588423964'}
{'x': '0.8977067858298895', 'y': '0.0915250471034454', 'z': '0.5994045156799004'}
{'x': '0.1742665415904057', 'y': '0.3420150165219624', 'z': '0.6031464526385122'}
{'x': '0.4219486318660017', 'y': '0.3397275847827785', 'z': '0.5972818153032335'}
{'x': '0.6818585097829839', 'y': '0.3402603219764870', 'z': '0.5960939583330003'}
{'x': '0.6605938016347537', 'y': '0.8211262131757806', 'z': '0.2511635759660038'}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! That is what I effort.

Answer (score 0):

1. Don't use regex for simple substring check. Use `substring in string`.
2. Don't `.readlines()` - that way you put all your data in memory. For larger files, it will hurt.
3. If I were you, I'd store both vectors and points as lists of tuples, not as 3 separate lists.

Assuming vectors always come first, we only need a flag to determine whether we're doing points already or not.

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    with open('data.txt') as f:
        p = None # we'll read this as well
        vectors = []
        points = []
        points_flag = False
        for line in f:
            parts = line.split()
            if len(parts) == 2: 
                points_flag = True # we don't even have to check line's contents, this line is the only one that has 2 parts
                p = int(parts[1])
                continue
            elif len(parts) == 3:
                if points_flag:
                    points.append((float(parts[0]), float(parts[1]), float(parts[2])))
                else:
                    vectors.append((float(parts[0]), float(parts[1]), float(parts[2])))
    # let's check the contents
    print(vectors)
    print(p)
    print(points)
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your useful advice. I learnt a new approach.

Answer (score 0):

```
class Base:
    """Base contains the common functionality for points and vectors"""
    __slots__ = '_x', '_y', '_z'

    def __init__(self, x, y, z):
        self._x = x
        self._y = y
        self._z = z

    @property
    def x(self):
        return self._x

    @property
    def y(self):
        return self._y

    @property
    def z(self):
        return self._z


class Point(Base):
    """Empty for now, the common functionality is enough"""


class Vector(Base):
    """Empty for now, the common functionality is enough"""


vectors = []
paramenter = 0.0
n_points = 0
points = []
with open('data.txt', 'r') as f:
    klass = None
    for line in f:
        if "Vectors" in line:
            klass = Vector
            continue
        elif "Points" in line:
            klass = Point
            n_points = int(line.split()[1])
            continue
        parts = line.split()
        if len(parts) == 1:
            parameter = float(parts[0])
        elif len(parts == 3):
            if klass == Vector:
                vectors.append(Vector(float(parts[0]), float(parts[1]), float(parts[2])))
            elif klass == Point:
                points.append(Point(float(parts[0]), float(parts[1]), float(parts[2])))
            else:
                raise Exception  # This will only happen if klass is something different
        else:
            raise ValueError  # This will only happen if it reads a line with 2 or more than 4 parts excluding the ones containing "Vectors" and "Points"

if n_points != len(points):
    raise ValueError("Unexpected number of points")
```

Comment: Thank you! I really appreciate your help!